# Activate conda enviroment automatically when starting VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

**Setting**

Suppose that I got a project called `my_project` that uses a python interpreter from a specific conda environment called `my_env`. When I set the interpreter of the project I will get the following settings.json file inside the `.vscode`  directory of `my_project`:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "<path to conda>/envs/my_env/bin/python"
}
```

**Problem**

With this configuration I would expect VSCode to automatically activate `my_env` in the terminal everytime I open `my_project`. But typically when I open `my_project` only the `base` environment of anaconda is activated in the terminal. To activate `my_env` I got different options that are all manual.

1. `conda activate my_env`
2. Press `strg+shift+p` and execute `create new integrated terminal`
3. Start a debug session

Probably there are even more ways of doing it.

**Question**

How can I avoid this stuff such that VSCode simply activates `my_env` automatically inside the integrated terminal when I open `my_project`.

**Further Informations**

- OS: Linux
- VSCode: 1.36
- Conda: 4.7.10

Answer (score 2):

Open Powershell and run as Administrator, execute the following command

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Then restart VS Code

Comment: Well this doesn't really solve the issue. I still want to have the base env active when I open a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Another way out would be to create shortcut for activation.For eg in ~/.bashrc do the following

```
alias a="conda activate my_env"
alias d="conda deactivate"
```

So now you need to just type `'a'` to activate and `'d'` to deactivate.

Comment: Hmm seems like this is a global configuration then. If I would use this, I would prefer that this shortcut only works for the specific project that I am working in. Otherwise I need to create shortcuts for every environment, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The Python extension for VS Code will pick up and support conda environment as long as you have specified a Python version when you created your conda environment and you gave it a name (see the [docs on environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments)).

And one way to work around this if you can't create an environment as required above is to use `conda run` which will handle the activation for you when running your code.

Comment: Why would I have to specify the python version? By default it will install the same python version as in the environment that I am currently using. My problem isn't that I can't run my python files. I just want `my_env` to be active in the integrated terminal of VSCode, when I open `my_project`. So that I can directly start ipython for example with the packages that I need for `my_project`.

Comment: @pafi you need to create your conda environment with a specified Python version due to how conda environments work and how we are able to detect them for activation.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Following [this doc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) at step two it says, that it uses the same version of python that I'm currently using as default. If I would specify the version explicitly, how would that change my environment?

Comment: @pafi It's a technical thing with conda that users aren't directly exposed to but that we rely on for conda environment detection in the extension.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an workspace folder
2. Inside the create file post the following code:

> ```
> {
>   "folders": [
>       {
>           "path": "."
>       }
>   ],
>   "settings": {
>       "python.condaPath": "/home/pcuser/anaconda3/condabin/conda",
>       "python.pythonPath": "/home/pcuser/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python",
>       "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
>       "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
>       
>   }
> }
> ```

3. Save configuration and close vscode
4. Open vscode.

It will select automatically the conda enviroment (Should appear at the bottom left of vscode).
Inside terminal 'my_env' will also be selected. If vscode doesn't select the 'Python Selected Interpreter' before you open the terminal the my_env inside terminal won't be selected. Open the terminal after the my_env is selected by vscode

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was simply opening User Settings (JSON), and adding the setting:

```
      "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
```

Comment: This doesn't do it for me. What OS and which shell are you using? For me it's Ubuntu 22.04 with zsh.

Comment: That was Windows 11 native with miniforge3 -- not totally germane to this question, come to think of it.  In Ubuntu (and Debian and Arch for that matter) I've never had to do *anything* to get my terminal to pick up the environment.

Answer (score -1):

I do have faced similar problem when I have multiple python project having virtual environments in system.

Since I was switching project based on workload, its difficult to activate right environment for specific project.

As VSCODE contain settings.py which store python path to use in particular project. But was not activating automatically.

I followed below step and its very fast compared to other method I searched.

Step 1. Delete current terminal. You will see bin icon as in below pic.

[image]

Step 2. Now start new terminal by shortcut.

CTRL + `

You will see VSCODE auto detect python path settings and activate the environment.

Simple