# How to setting vscode initial terminal code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to change `envs` to other because envs is env folder.

```bash
conda activate /Users/x/miniconda3/envs
(base) ➜  cs git:(main) ✗ conda activate /Users/x/miniconda3/envs

EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /Users/x/miniconda3/envs
```

When i click[image], the path is correctly set.

Is there anything I can set in VScode to do such thing? I need this setting globally.

**Now I can set task.json in workspace to do so, but still not global.**

```
setting.json
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/x/miniconda3/bin/python",
"python.condaPath": "/Users/x/miniconda3",
```

My expected outcome:

```
# new terminal open
conda activate <my_env_name_according_to_interpret_i_choose>
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63395195/8658598) should help.

Comment: @doneforaiur, yeah but only work locally, I'm thinking maybe somewhere wrongly configured

Answer (score 1):

Sicne you want to activate conda on startup for every workspace:

1. `ctrl+shift+p`
2. Preferences : Open Default Settings (JSON)
3. Add your `conda` path to:

   ```
   "terminal.integrated.env.<your OS>": {
      "PATH": "/Users/<username>/miniconda3/<env>"
   }
   ```

Comment: Im using macos, and after did that setting, don't have any auto active script..`"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "PATH": "/Users/x/miniconda3/envs"
  },`

Comment: `"python.condaPath": "/Users/<username>/miniconda3/<env>",` ? Are you absolutely sure that the path to conda env is correct since there's a `EnvironmentLocationNotFound`?

Comment: conda3/<env> or  conda3/envs/env?

Comment: Is there a `env` folder inside the `envs` folder?

Comment: yes, when you create env , new folder added in envs/

Comment: no matter how i change that path, it still /envs

Comment: Other than minor inconvenience, I don't think that will interfere much. Then, you should use `miniconda3/envs/env` whenever you want to use that environment.

Comment: still not work.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python-environment-manager

then I can set correct env now.

**I don't know if there exist someway I can set auto activate  without a plugin?**